# Telas Responsivas

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Estou com duvidas sobre telas responsivas no android.
Estou quase finalizando meu app, mas não estou conseguindo fazer que ele fique responsivo as varias tamanhos de telas.
Estou usando a IDE Android Studio.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_home_calcular"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_calcular_efeito" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="205dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_home_aluno"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_aluno_efeito" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_home_fluxograma"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_fluxograma_efeito" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/button_home_notas"
    android:background="@drawable/botao_notas_efeito" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Essa imagem é um exemplo do meu layout.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você poderia complementar com algum código exemplo que você está usando...

Comment: Há várias formas de tornar um layout ajustável às várias dimensões de tela. Cada uma delas depende do conteúdo do layout(imagens por exemplo) e até do tipo de aplicação. Foi por isso que a sua pergunta foi fechada como **"amplo demais"**. Se a questão tem apenas haver com essa tela poste o xml do seu layout.

Comment: A pergunta continua fechada por isso não posso responder. O problema do seu layout é que, apesar de você usar um RelativeLayout, está, para posicionar os botões, a usar atributos de posicionamento fixo como marginTop, marginLeft e não relativos como layout_alignParentLeft, layout_toRightOf, etc.

Comment: Olá, como você conseguiu fazer os botões assim,redondos?

Answer (score 1):

**Sempre siga as convenções sobre as melhores práticas de codificação do Android**, elas foram tomadas por um motivo e você não precisa reinventar a roda, isso é certamente a melhor atitude que você pode tomar.

Falando brevemente, você terá que criar "a mesma" activity para cada tipo de dispositivo que deseja atender. E em casa activity utilizar os diferentes resources para cada tamanho de tela. Por exemplo: `layout-hdpi` e `layout-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi` e `drawable-xhdpi`, etc. O código abaixo foi retirado da primeira fonte dessa pergunta e mostra um exemplo dessa escolha de qual activity mostrar.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate();
        Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();

        if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity_tablet);
        } else {
            setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fontes:**

- [New Tools for Managing Screen Sizes](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)
- [Supporting Multiples Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Você terá de ler melhor o conteúdo dos *links* que indicou porque, pela sua resposta, julgo que não entendeu que o código que postou não é necessário se for utilizado o *"Screen Size Selector"*

Comment: Obrigado pelo feedback, resposta corrigida.

Comment: Eduardo Silva, esse 600 (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) que tem no código é que vale a telas maiores que 600 dp?